# How to fix CMake Fortran modules dependency?

Tags: module, cmake, fortran, dependencies

Hi I have a Fortran project with the following directory order

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/module_1.f90     (Fortran Modules)
src/module_2.f90
src/... (more files)
```

module_1.f90 depends on module_2.f90.

The simplified CMakeLists.txt is:

```
project(MyProject LANGUAGES Fortran)
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.f90)
add_executable(MyExec SOURCES)
```

I get the dependency error:

```
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘module_2.mod’ :for reading at (1): The file or directory doesn't exist.
```

I tried:

```
include_directories(src)
```

without positive results.

if you search in the build directory:

```
find . -name "module_2*"
```

nothing exits so the module_2 is not compiled before module_1. Why this happens ?

**Edited:**

I found the problem at the end. In `module_1` I had a pragma (which are not originally supported by Fortran) that was like:

```
#ifdef VAR
    module_1_function
#endif
```

and in my CMakeLists.txt I declared:

```
 set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -DVAR=2")
```

When CMake was creating the dependency tree it was not taking into account this variable. To do it right I had to do the last in the following way:

```
 add_definitions(-DVAR=2)
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting all .mod files into one directory, for larger projects, there is a cleaner solution, defining a function:

```
function(add_fortran_library LIB)
    add_library(${LIB} ${ARGN})

    # set module path to LIB_DIR/mod
    get_target_property(LIB_DIR ${LIB} BINARY_DIR)
    set_target_properties(${LIB} PROPERTIES Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${LIB_DIR}/mod)

    # making LIB_DIR/mod available for libraries linking LIB 
    target_include_directories(${LIB} INTERFACE ${LIB_DIR}/mod)
endfunction(add_fortran_library)
```

If you now use add_fortran_library() instead of add_library() you don't have to care about the modules anymore.

Comment: Please do not post the same answers under multiple questions. If they questions are the same, they should be linked as duplicates instead.  If they are not the same, adjust the answer to fit the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell CMake where to place and find modules.

I use the following, but of course the specific location is up to you.

```
set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules)
```

Place the line above before any `include_directory` or `add_executable` command.

Comment: The problem continues to be there. Now the folder `modules` has appeared in the `build` directory but the `module_2.mod` doesn't exist there.

Comment: For futher debugging, please 1. remove all files from the build directory (to remove cache) and rerun cmake for a clean build and 2. Try to list the files explicitly: `add_executable(MyExec src/module_1.f90 src/module_2.f90 src/main_program.f90`) for instance.

Comment: Hi, Pierre I tried the first one and continues. The second one it is more complicated because this is a big project of about 500 source files. I wrote only a simplification of the project.

Comment: What version of cmake?

Comment: A single executable or several?

Comment: `cmake version 3.7.2` and **one** executable.

Comment: CMake supposedly finds the dependencies automatically, so this is a bit surprising. Ideally, you should build a [mcve].

Comment: You are right, I will try to do it in some minutes trying to reproduce this.

Comment: Hi Pierre the problems were at the pragmas inside the module. I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I don't know what should be done with the question though.